# How to elide inferable trait generics in rust

Tags: generics, rust

Let's say I have the following traits, where I have a bunch of concrete implementations. For each concrete TokenParser there is only ever one concrete TokenHolder for it.

```
trait Token {}
trait TokenHolder<T: Token> {}
trait TokenParser<H: TokenHolder<T>, T: Token> {}
```

I have a bunch of code that consumes TokenParser and would like to cut down on the amount of boilerplate that I have. I feel like there should be a way of doing that like

```
trait TokenParser<H: TokenHolder<T: Token>> {}
// or
trait TokenParser<H: TokenHolder<T>> where T: Token {}
```

Comment: The problem is that generics are exactly the _opposite behavior_ of what you describing: multiple `impls` with different generics. You're using the wrong tool. You should use associated types. See [their RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0195-associated-items.md).

Comment: Thanks for pointing me towards to proper name of this pattern. The examples in the question are actually an improvement over what I had before where TokenHolder wasn't generic and I was passing around `H`s and `T`s everywhere without any enforcement of their coupling ‍♂️.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can't really be achieved using generics but can be used with an [associated type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/associated-items.html#associated-types) within `TokenHolder`

```
trait TokenHolder {
    type Token: Token;
}

trait TokenParser<H: TokenHolder> {
    // This signature demonstrates using the type on the holder
    // in the signature for the parser.
    fn extract_token(holder: H) -> H::Token;
}
```

---

###### Updated

Updating to use official term based on Chayim Friedman's comment.